# What Prevents This JavaScript For Loop from Looping Infinitely?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am definitely a novice when it comes to JavaScript. I have searched around stackoverflow and the web for an explanation as to why this JavaScript for loop does not loop infinitely, but I have yet to find a clear answer. I am currently using this loop, a loop that I borrowed and modified, on my website and it is working as intended; however, I would like to know why it isn't looping infinitely. I was under the impression that the first statement of a for loop defines the loop variable, the second sets the looping condition (which prevents an infinite loop), and the third modifies the loop variable after the code block has been executed. Why is this loop not looping infinitely if it lacks a loop condition statement?

```
function showAll() {
    var aBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.aBox');
    for (var i = a.Boxes.length; i--;) {
        aBoxes[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the variable "i" is finally decremented to 0, the value of `i--` will be "falsy" and the loop will terminate. The loop does not lack a condition expression; that's what `i--` is.

Comment: It took you 45 seconds to open the question, to read it entirely and post an answer...

Comment: @VisioN ah ... well it was pretty clear what he was asking :) The last sentence says it all really.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I also find myself reading the question from the tail, but very often some minor part gets missed somewhere in the middle `:)`

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for the super quick answer! So "i--" functions as a condition that must be met and modifies the loop variable (I'm probably butchering terminology here).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is one of the "clever" ways to write a `for` loop that should be avoided for their cleverness. There is no advantage over a traditional `for` loop and it raises questions while reading it. (In other words: I consider "clever" code a code smell.)

Comment: @Tomalak yes that's a good point - I've still got an "inner C programmer" that doesn't mind it because it's so idiomatic, but it's definitely a quirky way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `i--`; is not `0`, it will be evaluated to `true`, hence the loop will continue. When it reaches `0`, which evaluates to `false`, it will stop

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't lack a loop condition statement. It lacks the modifying statement. One lacking the second condition would look like this:

```
for (var i = a.Boxes.length; ; i--)
```

What **your** loop is doing is decrementing `i` whenever it's time to check the loop condition statement and then checking to see if the resulting value is true or false (i.e. non-zero or zero). When `i` gets small enough (`i==0`) this will terminate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The loop isn't missing the condition expression; it's missing the expression that occurs at the end of each loop iteration (the third expression). However, `i` is decremented as a *side-effect* of the condition expression, so a final expression is not needed.

The condition expression evaluates to `false` once `i` reaches `0` and so the loop terminates.

More generally, each of the expressions in a `for` statement is optional. It is perfectly fine to omit any or all of them.